# Is it possible to have more than 4 parameters in an AssemblyVersion?

Tags: .net, version, .net-assembly

Just want to know if it's possible to have more than 4 parameters in an AssemblyVersion for a .Net assembly?

What I'm trying to achieve is versioning on the following format:

```
<Major>.<Minor>.<Maintenance>.<Revision>.<BuildNumber>
```

.. And if it is not possible, can anyone recommend any other way to achieve what I'm trying, such as concatenating numbers or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible, not sure why you require a fifth number tho, but you could put it in the AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute instead, that is the "visual representation", not a strict version number, just a string. This is shown as "Product version" in properties/details on the dll/exe.

I use it to show alpha/beta releases, like so:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("0.4.1207.1101")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("0.4.1207.1101")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("0.4-alpha")]
```